# How does this code remove duplicates from a sorted array?

Tags: java, arrays

If I pass in a number, an array `2, 3, 3, 3, 1`, for example. It removes the duplicates of 3, but why? and the result is 123 (which it should, because of the sorting method).

`Sortering.sorterHeltallstabell(tab)` is only sorting my code, while the rest removes the duplicates. It gets sorted before duplicates are removed.

Why does this code remove duplicates of an array when you pass it into the method?

```
public static int[] utenDubletter(int[] tab){
    Sortering.sorterHeltallstabell(tab);

    if (tab.length < 2)
        return tab;

    //why does this code remove duplicates?
    int j = 0;
    int i = 1;

    while (i < tab.length) {
        if (tab[i] == tab[j]) {
            i++;
        } else {
            j++;
            tab[j] = tab[i];
            i++;
        }           
    }              
    int[] B = Arrays.copyOf(tab, j + 1);
    return B;
}
```

Comment: please tag `java`. otherwise people won't know you what you are talking about

Comment: I only asked one question. Why does the part I am showing you here, remove duplicates? Thanks.

Comment: Well, it does so because of the `while` loop in the middle. Do you understand how that works?

Comment: I am sorry about that, I was trying to write a rensponse and pressed enter to go to next line, and it posted. I am giving a response now.

Comment: You can always delete comments if you made them by mistake.

Comment: 112223, with index 012345, j = 0 and i = 1. first round, while i is less than the length of tab, do this: if tab(i) is equal to tab(j), increase i by1, else increase j by 1 and copy the tab(j) equal to tab(i), and then increase i by one. when this is done copy, tab into an array with j+1 indexes, and return it

Comment: OK, so where is the problem?

Comment: when I follow the the code through, step by step, I never get the right result. I am going to follow the code through and u can see.

Comment: step through with a simple case of tab=[1,1] to see what happens, then move on to a more complex one

Comment: Note that if you want to add any complex explanation you shouldn't do it in the comments, as they allow only short one-line explanations or questions. You should add it to your question instead.

Comment: Okey, I realized I can't even do it with 112. index is 012, and numbers are 112. because i is one less than 2, i will go into the while sentence once. is tab[1] equal to tab[0], yes. so lets increase i with i++. i is now 2, and j is 0. i is not lower than tab.length anymore so no more while sentence. so copy from this array the length 1, this means 0, and 1? but if u want me to copy two indexes how can it know which one because i have 3 indexes, right, 0,1,2.:(

Comment: tab.length is 3 in that example, not 2, you terminated your loop too early. The iteration you missed makes tab[1,2,2], j == 1.  The loop terminates at i == 3.  Array.copyOf keeps the first elements it encounters up to the value of the second parameter (2, in your case).  Therefore, [1,2] is returned.

Comment: Remember, length is not the position of the final index, it is the number of indexes in your array.  Index at position 0 is still an index, so an array consisting of a single element at index 0 is still of length 1.

Comment: It should be noted that this code might not be a good example, since its in-place rearrangement of the original array is a destructive side-effect.

Comment: I think i knew this. but i am not sure so i am asking for confirmation, in 2,2,4,6,6 the length is 5. i goes to 4, and stops at the first 6 number.

Comment: I think all of you have been very helpful so I can't pick a best answer. It was a combination of the text comments, and the simulation, and I just realized I have had flaws in my while loops. 1 less 2. i thought u couldn't go past that, but u can because its still less than 2. thanks :>

Answer (score 3):

Dig this simulation:

```
Start
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
 j  i
Duplicate found (tab[i] == tab[j]), move i over 1 (i++)
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
 j     i
Duplicate found, move i over 1
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
 j        i
Non-duplicate (else); adding 1 to j (j++), 
    copying element i to el j (tab[j] = tab[i]), 
    adding 1 to i (i++)
[1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
    j        i
Duplicate found, move i over 1
[1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
    j           i
Duplicate found, move i over 1
[1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
    j              i
Non-duplicate; adding 1 to j, copying i to j, adding 1 to i
[1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3]
       j              i
i == tab.length, so stop
Copy first 3 elements of array (up to j) to result 
    (int[] B = Arrays.copyOf(tab, j + 1)) and return it
```

Comment: thanks this helped me very much. and its too funny you edited my OP

Comment: I think all of you have been very helpful so I can't pick a best answer. It was a combination of the text comments, and the simulation, and I just realized I have had flaws in my while loops. 1 less 2. i thought u couldn't go past that, but u can because its still less than 2. thanks :>

Answer (score 3):

This works because the code under

```
if (tab[i] == tab[j])
```

iterates through the sorted array, skipping duplicated elements and instead copying each unique element forward to the front part of the array, just after the already scanned (and known to be unique elements).  It then only keeps that front part of the array.

Stepping through the code:

```
if (tab.length < 2)
    return tab;

int j = 0;
int i = 1;
```

Method gets input: [1,1,1,2,2,2,3], is sorted (since the input is already sorted in this example, there is no change), tab is greater than 2, so do not return.
j is assigned the value 0
i is assigned the value 1

```
while (i < tab.length) { ... }
```

i (which is 1) is less than the tab length (which is 7).  While loop is entered:

```
    if (tab[i] == tab[j]) {
        i++;
    } else {
        j++;
        tab[j] = tab[i];
        i++;
    }
```

Iteration 1: 
tab[i], which is tab[1], which is 1, is compared to tab[j], which is tab[0], which is 1.  They are equal, so i is incremented.  i is now 2.

Iteration 2:
tab[i] (tab[2], or 1) is compared to tab[j] (tab[0] or 1).  They are equal, so i is incremented.  i is now 3.

Iteration 3:
tab[i] (tab[3], or 2) is compared to tab[j] (tab[0] or 1).  They are not equal.  j is incremented, and is now 1.  tab[j] (tab[1]) is assigned the value of tab[i] (tab[3]).  tab is now [1,2,1,2,2,2,3].  i is incremented, and is now 4.

Iteration 4:
tab[i] (tab[4], or 2) is compared to tab[j] (tab[1] or 2).  They are equal, so i is incremented.  i is now 5.

Iteration 5:
tab[i] (tab[5], or 2) is compared to tab[j] (tab[1] or 2).  They are equal, so i is incremented.  i is now 6.

Iteration 6:
tab[i] (tab[6], or 3) is compared to tab[j] (tab[1] or 2).  They are not equal.  j is incremented, and is now 2.  tab[j] (tab[2]) is assigned the value of tab[i] (tab[6]).  tab is now [1,2,3,2,2,2,3].  i is incremented, and is now 7.

I is now no longer less than the length of tab, we exit the while loop.

```
int[] B = Arrays.copyOf(tab, j + 1);
return B;
```

B is created by copying tab up to length j + 1, or 3, starting from the first element.  B is now [1,2,3].

Method returns [1,2,3], as expected.

Comment: I think all of you have been very helpful so I can't pick a best answer. It was a combination of the text comments, and the simulation, and I just realized I have had flaws in my while loops. 1 less 2. i thought u couldn't go past that, but u can because its still less than 2. thanks :>

Answer (score 2):

It is obvious that with the line

```
if (tab[i] == tab[j])
```

you can skip an element of the array if two consecutive elements are the same.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few important considerations for this duplicate removal portion of the code.

- It is actually overwriting the contents of the array in the middle of determining duplicates.  It's using the front part of the array (which has already been checked previously) to store the contents of the non-duplicates.  Since Java passes objects by value (specifically value of reference), changes to the local copy of the parameter won't be propagated back in the calling method.  This is not true for languages that pass objects by reference (like C#), so this algorithm would not work there.
- This algorithm depends on the fact that sorting the array puts all of the same duplicate into a single continuous block of indexes.  This guarantees that all future elements will never match something that was previously overwritten many iterations ago (because it is at least the size of the current maximum, else the array wasn't actually sorted properly).

Heavily commented explanation

```
public static int[] utenDubletter(int[] tab){
    //sort the array
    Sortering.sorterHeltallstabell(tab);

    //There must be at least 2 elements for any duplicate to exist
    if (tab.length < 2)
        return tab;

    int j = 0; //index of the largest element in the new array found so far
    int i = 1; //index of the current index of the array being checked

    while (i < tab.length) {
        //if it's a duplicate 
        if (tab[i] == tab[j]) {
            i++;    //just skip this element and check the next one
        } else {
            j++;    //since this number does not exist in the new array make space for it 
            tab[j] = tab[i];    //record this new element
                                //we have checked this element (with i) before this 
                                //so we don't need to keep it around any longer
            i++;    //move onto the next element 
        }           
    }              
    int[] B = Arrays.copyOf(tab, j + 1);    //copy only the elements that we actually 
                                            //manually overwrote. Since arrays are
                                            //0-indexed, add one to the final index (j)
                                            //for the number of elements in our new array.
    return B;
}
```

Comment: thanks, to this and the other answers. i think i am starting to get it. it copies all the numbers to the left, and then makes an array that is big enough for that.

Comment: @DavidLund if you find answers helpful, consider upvoting them.  You can also accept the one answer that solved your problem "the best".  These are both voluntary actions that your are in no way obligated to do.

Comment: Sometimes all these labels confuses me. can i just ask u one more thing if this is correct? i am always a little confused by objects and all that stuff. if i have a class pet(int i), and i make pet something = new pet(1). pet is the object right, and something is the reference to the object pet, and (int i) is the parameter, and (1) is the argument?

Comment: What do you mean by "labels"?  The code comments?  Or the poorly-named variables `i` and `j`?

Comment: Sometimes all these labels confuses me. can i just ask u one more thing if this is correct? i am always a little confused by objects and all that stuff. if i have a class pet(int i), and i make pet something = new pet(1). pet is the object right, and something is the reference to the object pet, and (int i) is the parameter, and (1) is the argument?

Comment: I think all of you have been very helpful so I can't pick a best answer. It was a combination of the text comments, and the simulation, and I just realized I have had flaws in my while loops. 1 less 2. i thought u couldn't go past that, but u can because its still less than 2. thanks :>

Comment: @DavidLund that's fair, so you should probably not accept any answer.  Best of luck.